# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined at l (froogaloop2.min.js?ver=4.8.3:1)

Tags: jquery, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player, froogaloop

I have Implemented Vimeo Video on hover and it works fine, but the Issue am facing is whenever I hover over that div the video is playing properly but it does not pause when I hover outside that div(mouseout).

Please find the below Js Code:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','.play-video',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var videoUrl = $(this).attr('href');
        //alert(videoUrl);
        $('#videoBox_'+videoUrl).show();
        $(this).next('#videoBox_'+videoUrl).html('<iframe id="player_'+videoUrl+'" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/' + videoUrl + '?api=1&amp;player_id=player_'+videoUrl+'&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
        var player = $("#player_"+videoUrl);
        //console.log(player[0].id);
        player.mouseover(function(){
            froogaloop = $f(player[0].id);
            froogaloop.api('play');
        });

        player.mouseout(function(){
            froogaloop = $f(player[0].id);
            froogaloop.api('pause');
        });
    });
```

I am getting an error while on the console:
[image]

Comment: Have you've solved your problem now?

Comment: The problem is not solved yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to propose another alternative for this case. In order to play / pause certain vimeo video clips, We can tweak some of your given code like this:

Sample Reference Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // 1) Assign a given variable called oPlayer
    var oPlayer = undefined;

    $('.container .item').on('mouseenter', '.play-video', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // 2) When user hover the hovered [iframe], The oPlayer
        // will now be assigned to that given [iframe] element
        oPlayer = $(this);
        froogaloop = $f(oPlayer[0].id);
        froogaloop.api('play');

   }).mouseleave(function() {

        // 3) So by the time the user leaves that
        // iframe, It will pause that given [iframe]
        froogaloop = $f(oPlayer[0].id);
        froogaloop.api('pause');
    });
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle for further reference: https://jsfiddle.net/85dLbt2u/5/

Hope this helps your given case.

Comment: I tried implementing this simpler code too.but i am still facing the same issue have a look at this page: http://rushabhmutha.com/aispi/shops/

Comment: Alright, I'll take a look and see if we can fix the problem

Comment: I've checked the given website's source code. Is this where you've set your given code snippet for using the `frogaloop`? http://rushabhmutha.com/aispi/wp-content/themes/aispi-theme/js/main.js?ver=4.8.3

Comment: Yes,we are using frogaloop in the main.js

Comment: I dont see the changes as what I've posted above. Its still the same. Any reason why?